# Get image from MP3 file with Java ID3 Tag library

Tags: java, tags, mp3, id3

I am trying to use [Java ID3 Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) to get image from an mp3 file. I've already managed to get and edit most of the tags, but I have some problems with getting the image. What I've already learned is that image is stored inside a ID3v2 tag with header **APIC**. I tried to read it in a similar way that I did with other tags:

```
ID3v2_3 id3v2 = (ID3v2_3) mp3File.getID3v2Tag();
AbstractID3v2Frame frame = id3v2.getFrame("APIC");

if (frame != null) {
    FrameBodyAPIC frameBody = (FrameBodyAPIC)frame.getBody();
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that whatever MP3 file I load in the application, the **APIC** frame is `NULL`. I'm sure that the song has a picture assigned as it's correctly displayed in Windows Media Player. Has anyone used the [Java ID3 Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) library and managed to load the song's picture? I'd be grateful for any help.

---

**Update**

I thought that it might be a problem with corrupted file or so. Therefore, I tried to set an image frame firstly and then try to read it. Unfortunately, with same result - the frame is always `null`. I present the code which I used:

```
public void setImage(ID3v2_3 id3v2, byte[] image) {
    AbstractID3v2Frame frame = id3v2.getFrame("APIC");

    // frame is always null
    if (frame == null) {
        frame = new ID3v2_3Frame();
    }

    FrameBodyAPIC frameBody = (FrameBodyAPIC) frame.getBody();

    if (frameBody == null) {
        frameBody = new FrameBodyAPIC();
    }

    frameBody.setObject("Picture Data", image);
    frameBody.setObject("MIME Type", "image/png");
    frame.setBody(frameBody);

    // Set the newly created frame to mp3 file
    id3v2.setFrame(frame);

    // frame is still null - even just after setting it!
    frame = id3v2.getFrame("APIC");
}
```

I used this method to update other tags and it works, however in this particular case it isn't. Does anyone know what can be a reason of that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code (untested, source: https://sourceforge.net/p/javamusictag/discussion/253424/thread/4300f7b1/ ) can help?

```
  187     private ImageData extractImageFromFile(String srcFile) throws Exception {
  188         ImageData imageData = null;
  189         File sourceFile = new File(srcFile);
  190         MP3File mp3file = new MP3File(sourceFile);
  191         FilenameTag fileNameTag = mp3file.getFilenameTag();
  192         AbstractID3v2 id3v2 = mp3file.getID3v2Tag();
  193         if (id3v2 != null) {
  194             AbstractID3v2Frame apic = id3v2.getFrame(PICTURE_TAG);
  195             if (apic != null) {
  196                 AbstractMP3FragmentBody apicBody = apic.getBody();
  197                 String mimeType = (String) apicBody.getObject(MIME_TAG);
  198                 String fileExtension = getFileExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType);
  199                 if (fileExtension == null)
  200                     fileExtension = "jpg";
  201                 if (fileExtension.charAt(0) == '.')
  202                     fileExtension = fileExtension.substring(1);
  203                 Object bytes = apicBody.getObject(PICTURE_DATA_TAG);
  204                 if (bytes != null) {
  205                     imageData = new ImageData();
  206                     imageData.bytes = (byte[]) bytes;
  207                     imageData.fileExtension = fileExtension;
  208                 }
  209             }
  210         }
  211         return imageData;
  212     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the problem, because whatever I do, I get `null` instead of the picture frame. In the upper code, it's in line number 194: `AbstractID3v2Frame apic = id3v2.getFrame(PICTURE_TAG);`. And because I get `null`, the rest of the code is not executed. I've updated my question to present the problem better.